# I try to calculate between 2 table on mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Select sale.preselRef As ref,
  sale.name,
  sale.saledate,
  sale.grandtotal,
  sale.secid,
  sale.invoicetype As typ,
  Sum(sellnote.Paid group by sellnote.Code) As cash,

From sale left joint
  sellnote on ( sale.preselRef = sellnote.Code)
```

I try to use left joint but I can not make it correct sql statement, please correct it

Comment: What is desired output and what are you getting by running this query? Also its not `left joint` its `left join`.

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select sale.preselRef As ref,
    sale.name,
    sale.saledate,
    sale.grandtotal, 
    sale.secid,
    sale.invoicetype As typ,
    Sum(sellnote.Paid) As cash
From sale LEFT JOIN 
    sellnote on ( sale.preselRef = sellnote.Code) 
    GROUP BY sellnote.Code
```

-- don't put after cash as it is last in select statement.
-- group by should be put @ end

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select sale.preselRef As ref,
  sale.name,
  sale.saledate,
  sale.grandtotal,
  sale.secid,
  sale.invoicetype As typ,
  Sum(sellnote.Paid group by sellnote.Code) As cash,

From sale left join
  sellnote on ( sale.preselRef = sellnote.Code)
```